# Misterious MaintenanceLogs Feature

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, feature

In SharePoint Online, as part of the Modern Team site, there is a  **MaintenanceLogs** **Web** feature with the ID 8c6f9096-388d-4eed-96ff-698b3ec46fc4. This feature does not exist even in SharePoint 2019.

Does anyone know what this feature is supposed to do? I could not find any documentation describing it. I have checked if this feature exusted as part of a classic Team site and it it's not present there. So I am curious what this does exactly.

This is how I have retrieved this feature:

```
Get-PnPFeature -Scope Web
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MaintenanceLogs feature was added in 2018 and is responsible for adding the _catalogs/MaintenanceLogs library. It's hidden and I am not sure if we are supposed to manually activate it. But from what I can see by looking into the feature XML files, this feature is harmless and does not add anything except for the /_catalogs/MaintenanceLogs library.

MaintenanceLogs library is a legacy feature that was there since at least 2013. It contains logs containing site [collection upgrade information](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/upgrade-and-update/review-site-collections-upgraded-to-sharepoint-2013?redirectedfrom=MSDN). For some reason, it is still used in the modern team sites. Probably for some compatability reasons.

[image]

There might be a case when /_catalogs/MaintenanceLogs library is missing due to a glitch. In this case, you can activate this feature via the code:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ModernTeamSite"
$MaintenanceLogsFeatureID = "8c6f9096-388d-4eed-96ff-698b3ec46fc4"
Enable-PnPFeature -Identity $MaintenanceLogsFeatureID
```